# listview prompting user the item is empty in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a list that has 2 records, and also I have a button to prompt the user that the 3rd record is empty.

Here is my code:

```
If lvFabric2.Items(2).Text Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox("The 3rd record is empty")
end if
```

I always get this error: **"InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index"**

How can I prompt the user that the 3rd record is empty.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post more code? I'm guessing that somewhere you're passing "1" where you shouldn't be, but it isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: @RyanHenderson: Hi sir, I have just edited the error, its 2 and not 1, sorry. And also that is all my code, thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ironically, you're getting the error because the third item is null.

Try this instead:

```
If lvFabric2.Items.Count() < 3 OrElse lvFabric2.Items(2).Text Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox("The 3rd record is empty")
end if
```

This will show your message box if there is no third element, or if the third element is null.

Note that I'm not 100% sure of the syntax. "Count" may be a property, so you may need "Items.Count" instead.

EDIT: Fixed syntax from C# ("||") to VB ("OrElse")

Comment: Hi sir, the error is also the same, but with these code I have made a work around and now the code is working great, thanks for this! big help for me.

Comment: Edited to change from C# "or" syntax to VB (it's been a while since I wrote anything in VB)

Answer (score 0):

Try `If lvFabric2.Items(2).ToString().length = 0 Then`

Comment: Hi sir, the error is also the same, But I appreciate the help, thank you.